# Making microtype match TeXLive2019 on arXiv (TeXLive2016)

Tags: fonts, pdftex, microtype, arxiv

If I compile the same document locally, with pdflatex shipped with TeXLive2019 installed, I get a different pdf than if I compile the same sources on arXiv, which currently uses TeXLive2016.

I narrowed down the main issue to be a different behaviour of the `microtype` package. An MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I uploaded to arXiv the following files:

- the MWE above
- `microtype.sty`, `microtype-pdftex.def` and `microtype.cfg` from my distribution

I still get discrepancies (highlighted by overlaying the 2016-compiled document in red):

[image: discrepancies]

This is the log from arXiv, using `microtype` with the `verbose` option.

```
TeX log appears below
[verbose]: Creating arXiv submission AutoTeX object
[verbose]: *** Using TeX Live 2016 ***
[verbose]: Calling arXiv submission AutoTeX process
[verbose]: TeX/AutoTeX.pm: admin_timeout = minion
[verbose]: <llncs.cls> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <microtype.sty> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <main.tex> is of type 'LATEX2e'.
[verbose]: <microtype-pdftex.def> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <splncs04.bst> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <microtype.cfg> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <mathtools.sty> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <mhsetup.sty> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'main.tex'
[verbose]: arXiv Warning: user included plain hyperref directive.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hlatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/2920347/ && latex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=latex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def)) (./microtype.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(./microtype-pdftex.def) (./microtype.cfg))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (default): hdvips.

(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty)))
No file main.aux.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

[1] [2] (./main.aux)

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `main.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck) Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck) or use package `bookmark'.

)
Output written on main.dvi (2 pages, 8744 bytes).
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hlatex for the second time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/2920347/ && latex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=latex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def)) (./microtype.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(./microtype-pdftex.def) (./microtype.cfg))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (default): hdvips.

(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))) (./main.aux)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty)) (./main.out
) (./main.out) [1] [2] (./main.aux) )
Output written on main.dvi (2 pages, 8744 bytes).
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.aux' (1573234349 >= 1573234349)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.out' (1573234349 >= 1573234349)
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'main.dvi'
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/2920347/ && dvips -R2 -z 'main.dvi' -o )" 2>&1
[verbose]: dvi(h)ps said ...
This is dvips(k) 5.996 Copyright 2016 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2019.11.08:1732' -> main.ps
</texlive/2016/texmf-dist/dvips/base/texc.pro>
</texlive/2016/texmf-dist/dvips/base/texps.pro>
</texlive/2016/texmf-dist/dvips/base/special.pro>
</texlive/2016/texmf-dist/dvips/base/color.pro>
</texlive/2016/texmf-dist/dvips/base/hps.pro>.
</texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>[1] [2]
<./head.tmp><./body.tmp>
.
[verbose]: Backing up 'main.ps'. Going to change %%Title line.
[verbose]: %%Title: line found and changed.
[verbose]: Title change completed.
[verbose]: Backing up 'main.ps'. Going to add a name/date stamp to it.
[verbose]: OK, inserting the stamp
[verbose]: Stamping completed.
[verbose]: All done.

[verbose]: AutoTeX process succeeded
[verbose]: Processing DVI
[verbose]: Gzipping and moving main.dvi
[verbose]: Gzipping ...2920347/main.dvi
[verbose]: Processing postscript
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for llncs.cls
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for main.dvi
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for main.dvi.gz
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for main.ps
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for main.tex
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for mathtools.sty
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for mhsetup.sty
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for microtype-pdftex.def
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for microtype.cfg
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for microtype.sty
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for splncs04.bst
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for style
[verbose]: Gzipping ...2920347/main.ps
[verbose]: Moving .../2920347/main.ps.gz => .../2920347/tex_cache/2920347.ps.gz

[verbose]: Moving .../2920347/main.dvi.gz => .../2920347/tex_cache/2920347.dvi.gz

[verbose]: All generated files successfully moved.
[verbose]: ** AutoTeX job completed. **
```

Comment: There's been no change in font for pdfTeX, and there will likely never be. Can you post a short example?

Comment: As always on the site, plaase provide code (full example) that others can coipy and test. Several of us have access to several years of TL installations.

Comment: Ok, I verified that the `fontdimen` are the same on both systems by printing them out and comparing. I'll try to come up with a MWE

Comment: Ok, so I narrowed it down to two packages. First is `mathtools`, uploading the recent version with the sources solves the script placement issue I was having. The second is `microtype`.

Comment: What if you upload `lipsum`, too?

Comment: @cfr Same happens. My current hypotesis is that the different versions of pdflatex support different features of microtype. I can get more consistent behaviour if I disable expansion altogether.

Comment: And what if you explicitly call for expansion? (Just for the record, I get no difference between TL19 and TL16, e.g. in both cases the sixth line ends with "eu", like in your sample in blackl). Also, there were no changes in pdftex concerning microtype features that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Robert thanks for checking! This is strange. ArXiv adds some modification of its own (which I am not sure how I can get) like autoloading hyperref. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Hm, no idea. Does ArXiv provide the log file?

Comment: @Robert as a matter of fact it does! Should I post it?

Comment: yeah, best when loading microtype with the `verbose` option.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it: arxiv goes the latex->dvips route, and in that case, expansion will be disabled because it would lead to errors when running dvips (which doesn't know how to do expansion). So unless there's an option to use pdflatex instead, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Looking at the arxiv [help page](https://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex), it should suffice to add `\pdfoutput=1` to the beginning of your file.

Comment: @Robert I cannot believe it, it works. I keep rediscovering this stupid fix for many other problems and then I forget again. I don't get why this changes what microtype does, since the files seem to be compiled with pdftex anyway...

Comment: @Robert feel free to post that as an answer, it solves my problem

Comment: @Bordaigorl pdftex produces DVI in that mode - not PDF. So it doesn't put any glyphs in the output at all. It just puts boxes. So it can't do font expansion. It isn't embedding fonts the way it is when producing PDF. `dvips` handles that.

Comment: @cfr Interestingly, `dviluatex` (ie.luatex in dvi mode) manages to do font expansion in a way that doesn't make dvips choke.

Comment: @Robert Interesting. Font handling is so different with the newest engines that I wouldn't even begin to guess what might be going on in that case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As can be gleaned from the `log` file, your document is processed with `latex` (and then `dvips`) rather than `pdflatex`. Unlike the latter, `latex` does not allow automatic font expansion, which is therefore disabled by `microtype`, hence the discrepancies compared to your document compiled with `pdflatex`.

ArXiv's submission [help page](https://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex) states that adding the line

```
\pdfoutput=1
```

to the beginning of your document will ensure compilation with `pdflatex`, thus allowing  font expansion.

Comment: What tells latex was being used? I saw `pdfTeX` mentioned and erroneously ruled that out...

Comment: The line starting with `Running` contains the command `latex` and the output is a `dvi` file. That means `pdflatex` was used in DVI mode.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to miss that one *facepalm*.
Every time I have to work with arXiv I have to rediscover the `\pdfoutput=1` thing (it came up for all other submissions for different reasons!) I wonder why it is not just the default, or recommended more prominently